# Why doesn't the replace function replace in a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following code which is not replacing the values in my string. Not sure why

```
select top 10 marker_id,
stuff((select ',' + replace(t2.text,'=&gt;', '|')
from vMARKER_DIRECTIONAL_TEXT t2 
where t1.marker_id = t2.marker_id
for xml path('')),1,1,'') text
from vMARKER_DIRECTIONAL_TEXT t1 
group by marker_id

LAT:-88.303934 LON:154.632292,=&gt; PHONE DUTY MANAGER ON 5555555 (AH) OR 
INFO CENTRE ON xxxxxx (BH),=&gt; LOCKED GATE AT PARK ENTRANCE CODE TO ENTER 
IS 1234,=&gt; TRAVEL WEST 3600M ON ROAD TO BUS STOP
```

Comment: so it looks like your values have the tags on them in the field.  your STUFF function is replacing the open tag "<" with a blank by virtue of the code ..., 1, 1, ' '   Try replacing '=&gt;' with '>' and see if it picks up the close tags.  second option is to wrap the REPLACE around the STUFF function and see if that works.

Comment: I made my comment an answer.  please give me some SO swag :)  I also put an explanation that I hope will make sense of the "why" this happened

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment on the other answer, my comment was correct.

Replacing "& gt;"

in your REPLACE function with ">" worked.

This is because your FOR XML PATH function was encoding ">" as "& gt;" after your REPLACE function had executed on the text.  Only after your FOR XML PATH function has run will the > character be replaced with the encoding string.

Edit: had to add a space because SO kept showing ">" LOL, and I don't know how to make it show it as just a string.